# Populate markers and polylines independent of the base tile map used. (An alternative to Leaflet for android)

Tags: android, google-maps, leaflet, gis, mapbox

I want to create a maps application and want the base tile map be changable (google maps, map box, etc). What I want to do is have a transparent layer on top of tile map and draw all markers and paths on that top layer so that no matter which base tile map the user selects, markers and paths remains the same.

I am looking for an alternative to `leaflet` for android.

Comment: When you say "_an alternative [...] for android_", do you mean you build a native app? Or hybrid? (Typically with Cordova)

Comment: Native android app. @ghybs

Answer (score 1):

Since nearly all of the map programs you will use: [Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/), [Mapzen](https://www.mapzen.com/documentation/), etc all use similar logic of defining your map within the XML [Sample 1](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) or Sample 2 (Below):

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The approach you could use would be to have multiple maps defined in your layout, show or hide them depending upon whatever factors you need, and then utilize data stored within your Activity to populate them.

For example, say you wanted to use Markers like in your question, when you place the marker, grab the *latitude* (double), *longitude* (double), and *markerId* (String), store them into a List / Set of objects in your Activity and then when the map is swapped, you can 'place' the markers again as you have the same required values to draw said markers.

If you want to pull the Latitude and Longitude from Markers clicked, [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181945/get-latitude-and-longitude-of-marker-in-google-maps) has an example of how to do it.

With regards to your paths, you could record start and end latitude / longitude points and re-draw / place them on whichever map is in the visible front.

The same applies to your zoom level and any other misc item you want to store; you just need to find common denominators and use them stored in your dataset to place and re-draw on whichever map is in the foreground.

It really comes down to how you want to manage the data and how you will 'swap' between maps.

Bear in mind that this approach can be fairly CPU intensive if the maps all maintain their data in the background while non-visible. You should likely remove the markers and drawn paths whenever you move the map to invisible or gone.